# Gstreamer with UDP network capture->modify->stream Pipeline Error

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-capture

Summary: I'm trying to receive video by using gstreamer pipeline and then make some modification on received frame with opencv, finally want to send this frame to another host by using opencv gstreamer pipeline. All steps are running on UDP network. (udpsink)

I think the problem is that received video is converting wrong format when using write function.

**STEP 1:**

I am able to receive video with this pipeline from specific gstreamer plugin:

```
VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 !"
                    "rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=1 drop=true", CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

**STEP 2:**

I found some pipelines and tried almost everything but I wasn't able to send received video with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 !"
                        "rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=1 drop=true", CAP_GSTREAMER);
//int width  = cap.get(3);
//int height = cap.get(4);
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Could not read video file" << endl;
    return 1;
}

VideoWriter writer;
writer.open("appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,bitrate=800 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000"
            , 0, (double)30, Size(1280, 720), true);
if (!writer.isOpened()) {
    printf("=ERR= can't create video writer\n");
    return -1;
}

Mat frame;
while (true) {

    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
        break;

    /* Captured video will be processed here. Then send another IP. */

    writer << frame;

}
}
```

**What I have tried**:

I tried to send video to final destination with command line and it was successful.

1:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,framerate=20/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1000000 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

2:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,framerate=20/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=5000
```

Both of them are running without any problem.

I also looked into code snippets from the [source code](https://github.com/PX4/sitl_gazebo/blob/master/src/gazebo_gst_camera_plugin.cpp) that sends to video_capture pipeline.

```
  GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("sender");
  if (!pipeline) {
    gzerr << "ERR: Create pipeline failed. \n";
    return;
  }

  GstElement* dataSrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "AppSrc");
  GstElement* testSrc = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "FileSrc");
  GstElement* conv  = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "Convert");
  GstElement* encoder = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "AvcEncoder");
  GstElement* parser  = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "Parser");
  GstElement* payload = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "PayLoad");
  GstElement* sink  = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "UdpSink");
  if (!dataSrc || !testSrc || !conv || !encoder || !parser || !payload || !sink) {
    gzerr << "ERR: Create elements failed. \n";
    return;
  }

// gzerr <<"width"<< this->width<<"\n";
// gzerr <<"height"<< this->height<<"\n";
// gzerr <<"rate"<< this->rate<<"\n";

  // Config src
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(dataSrc), "caps",
      gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
      "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "I420",
      "width", G_TYPE_INT, this->width,
      "height", G_TYPE_INT, this->height,
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, (unsigned int)this->rate, 1,
      NULL),
      "is-live", TRUE,
      NULL);

  // Config encoder
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(encoder), "bitrate", 800, NULL);
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(encoder), "speed-preset", 2, NULL); //lower = faster, 6=medium
  //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(encoder), "tune", "zerolatency", NULL);
  //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(encoder), "low-latency", 1, NULL);
  //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(encoder), "control-rate", 2, NULL);

  // Config payload
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(payload), "config-interval", 1, NULL);

  // Config udpsink
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "host", this->udpIP.c_str(), NULL);
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "port", this->udpPort, NULL);
  //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "sync", false, NULL);
  //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "async", false, NULL);

  // Connect all elements to pipeline
  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), dataSrc, conv, encoder, parser, payload, sink, NULL);

  // Link all elements
  if (gst_element_link_many(dataSrc, conv, encoder, parser, payload, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
    gzerr << "ERR: Link all the elements failed. \n";
    return;
  }

  // Set up appsrc
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(dataSrc), "stream-type", 0, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);
  g_signal_connect(dataSrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(cb_need_data), this);

  // Start
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_main_loop_run(mainLoop);

  // Clean up
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
  g_main_loop_unref(mainLoop);
  mainLoop = nullptr;
```

Comment: I'm still facing with this problem but useful information about this problem can be found on this source: https://github.com/PX4/sitl_gazebo/blob/master/src/gazebo_gst_camera_plugin.cpp